Sensor size of Zed 2i stereo camera
I am trying to determine the sensor size in the Zed 2i stereo camera.  Based on the datasheet, which can be found here, it looks like each pixel is 2um x 2um and the sensor is 2688 x 1520 pixels. That would give the sensor a size of 5.376mm x 3.040mm.  Am I reading this data sheet correctly?


Roughly, yes.
They advertise the sensor as being "1/3" which means its diagonal is about 2/3 that, so 2/9" or 5.6mm (from your data is 6.17).

I think the pixel size is rounded up.  I get closer to 5.2x2.95 mm calculating from the diagonal of the sensor format and working backwards from the pixel density.
